# Create cocoa borderless window using nib design

Tags: cocoa, xcode

I am trying a full screen borderless full screen window. I can show it but it appears empty because I don't know how to tell it to use one of my NIB files. I am using following code to create the window:

```
int windowLevel = CGShieldingWindowLevel();   
NSRect screenRect;
screenRect = [[NSScreen mainScreen] frame];
ventanaBloqueo = [[Escucha alloc] 
           initWithContentRect:screenRect
           styleMask:NSBorderlessWindowMask
           backing:NSBackingStoreBuffered
           defer:NO 
           screen:[NSScreen mainScreen]];
```

where 'Escucha' is a NSWindow subclass. How could I tell the window use one of my NIB designs?

Regards

Answer (score 1):

I would use a window controller. It's much easier and more ordered.

For example:

```
NSWindowControllerSubclass* controller = [[NSWindowControllerSubclass alloc] initWithNibName:@"nibName"];
```

Comment: but I need to override initWithContentRect and force to be called. How can I do that using a controller?

Comment: Try it like this:[[window contentView] enterFullScreenMode:[NSScreen mainScreen withOptions:nil]; When I was you I would read a little bit about the windows. Try to understand the NSWindowController as well.